# A regularity result for semilinear PDE of the form $\Delta u=f(x, u)$ in Michael E. Taylor's book Partial Differential Equations III.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, nonlinear-analysis

Under the assumption that

$$\partial_{u} f(x, u) = 0 \text{ for } |u| \geq K \quad（1.6）$$

Michael E. Taylor said that (proposition $(1.3)$)

> For $k=1,2,..$, if $g \in H^{k+1 / 2}(\partial M)$ then any
> solution $u \in V$ to
>
> \begin{align} \Delta u &= f(x, u) \text{ on $M$} \\ u &= g \qquad \text{ on $\partial M$} \end{align}
>
> belongs to
> $H^{k+1}(M)$. Hence, if $g \in C^{\infty}(\partial M)$, then $u \in$
> $C^{\infty}(\bar{M})$ where $V = \{u \in H^{1}(M): u = g \text{ on } \partial M \}$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(\bar{M} \times \mathbb{R})$.

**Proof**

We start with $u \in H^{1}(M)$. Then the right side of $(1.1)$ belongs to $H^{1}(M)$ if $f(x, u)$ satisfies $(1.6)$. This gives $u \in H^{2}(M)$, provided $g \in H^{3 / 2}(\partial M)$. Additional regularity follows inductively.

I don't get it, can someone give me some hints?

Comment: What is $(1.1)$ and $(1.6)$? Should $(1.6)$ be $(1.3)$? Also, this is just a bootstrapping argument. What part don't you get?

Comment: (1.6) is $|u| \geq K, \partial_{u} f(x, u)=0$,  I confirmed again that it was really （1.6）.@mattos

Comment: You should put that in your post rather than a comment, because other people may not see it here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit it again. @mattos

Comment: This is a so-called bootstrap argument. You have to show that $u\in H^k$ for any $k$.  If so, then the desired property follows from the Morrey embedding theorem. Can you prove it when $g=0$? What part prevents you to proceed a proof?

Comment: Actually I don't even know how to prove the right side of (1.1) belongs to $H^{1}(M)$ if $f(x, u)$ satisfies (1.6) and u belongs to $H^{1}(M)$. @Will Kwon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the assumption (1.6) implies that there exists a constant $L$ such that
$$ |\partial_u f(x,u)|\leq L\quad \text{on } \overline{M}\times \mathbb{R}.$$
Suppose that $u \in H^1(M)$ and define
$$ h(x)=f(x,u(x)).$$
Since $|\partial_u f(x,u)|$ is bounded, it follows from the chain rule that
$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x,u(x))+f(x,u(x)) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x) \in L^2(M). $$
Hence $h$ is in $H^1$. Therefore, by $L^2$-theory, $u \in H^3$. Then continue this process.

---

November 28th, 2021. After receiving the comment, I think that it is necessary to explain several steps. I will focus on the case when $M=\Omega$, $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also, by the trace theorem, we may assume that $g=0$. Recall the following regularity theorem.

> **Theorem A.** Let $k\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ and $h\in H^k(\Omega)$. Then there exists a unique $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^{k+2}(\Omega)$ satisfying
> $$ -\Delta u=h\quad \text{in } \Omega,\quad u=0\quad \text{on } \partial\Omega.$$

Suppose that $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. By the previous argument, we see that $h(x)=f(x,u(x))$ belongs to $H^1(\Omega)$. By Theorem A, there exists a unique $v\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^3(\Omega)$ satisfying
$$ -\Delta v=h\quad \text{in }\Omega\quad v=0\quad \text{on } \partial\Omega.$$
Define $w=v-u$. Then $w\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $w$ satisfies
$$ -\Delta w=0\quad \text{in } \Omega\quad w=0\quad \text{on } \partial\Omega.$$
Hence by the uniqueness assertion in Theorem A, $w$ is identically zero. This implies that $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^3(\Omega)$. Continue this process.

Comment: Thanks for answering!But I'm confused whether it is $F$ or $f$, and if it is $f$,$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x_{j}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}(x, u(x))+$$\partial_{u} f(x, u)$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \in L^{2}(M)$, I know that $\partial_{u} f(x, u)$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}}(x) \in L^{2}(M)$, but why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}(x, u(x))$$\in L^{2}(M)$.

Comment: @TeenFromAlishan Is it $M$ is bounded set? According to Taylor's book, it is a compact Riemannian manifold. Since $f$ is a smooth function over $\overline{M}$, all of its derivatives are bounded. Since $M$ is bounded, we conclude that all of its derivatives are in $L^p(M)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm confused about the relationship between the regularity and the function space $g$ belongs to, where is $g$ used in the proving process.

Comment: @TeenFromAlishan I modified my answer to acting on your additional question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With your help, I have understood the proof method of this part of the book. @Will Kwon